# How to save/write Spark error message to log file in Python program script?

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, error-handling, pyspark

In my Python/Spark program script, I have

```
logger = logging.getLogger(results.app_name)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler(outputPath+".log")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
```

to add logger info (`logger.info()`) and *expected* errors under specific circumstances (`logger.error()`) to console and a custom log file (i.e., `outputPath+".log"`). However, when I get unexpected errors (e.g., program crashes, error on line whatever, timed out problems, datasets don't match), they only get printed on the console.

How do I also add debug/unexpected errors to the custom log file?

e.g., I got an error message printed on the console, but I like it to also be written in the log file automatically by the script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/lc/Documents/sparkprogram.py", line 747, in 
>       phenotypes, thresholds, r2All, pAll=regression(prsDict,pheno_file, pheno_delim, pheno_columns, pheno_no_header, covarColumns=covar_columns, outputName=outputPath, logger=logger)
>     File "/Users/lc/Documents/sparkprogram.py", line 298, in regression
>       assert samplesize==phenodata.shape[0], "Unequal sample size in pheno file and genotype data"
>   AssertionError: Unequal sample size in pheno file and genotype data

Comment: Are you explicitly printing to the console or are you leaving them as unhandled errors and the console is representing the errors to you?

Comment: If you're explicitly handling your errors, you would just log the error from within your error handler. If you are not handling your errors, then guard your code with validation rules and when you detect a validation error, write it to the log. Basic point is that you have to turn your unexpected errors into expected errors. "Program crashes" would be an outlier.

Comment: "timed out" can be anticipated.  "datasets do not match" can be anticipated. "error on line x" is something that should never make it to production. That's not an error to log. That's a defect in your code.  "Program crashed" would likely have to be handled by the context which executed the application.

Comment: Hi @K.AlanBates, thank you for your feedback. I'm not very familiar with the terminology (and I'm still an amateur Python/Spark user)... what are unhandled errors, guarding, and validation errors? I understand your point--it's best to be prepared for all sorts of problems so nothing is unexpected. The only way I can think of being fully prepared is to manually create all possible situations that I can think of that can break my code, but there will always be some unexpected errors that will be missed.

Comment: These unexpected errors are explicitly printed on the console. I would like them to also be automatically included in the custom log files, so that, e.g., when another user finds an error, they can send me the the log file and I can try to figure out what went wrong (e.g., Just recently a colleague said a file wasn't printing. Another colleague double checked the log file and reported that there was no is problems, so the code must be wrong and we should discard it. After I re-checked, it turns out that the console reported an issue with unequal sample size in their datasets.

Comment: I'd like that in the log file so the reports are saved.)

Comment: the "automatically" part of your desire is the trouble spot.  Since you volunteer that you are an amateur Python developer(are you also an amateur developer in general?) you will likely make the most hay by explicitly delivering your log messages to your Logger when the message is identified.  You can web search "Python Exception Handling" for more detailed information.